# How to adjust Network-Manager?

Tags: networking

I had a problem with login after sleep. It was asking for two times login password so I have looked in /etc/passwd file. I think may they are two accounts registered with the same ID. There was nothing. :/ But i have seen something named nobody and I have removed(i dont now why i have done). After rebooting the Laptop, Netork-Manager have not worked. So i have write in the terminal `'sudo service network-manager force-reload'` and its working but not after shutdown. I have to write it all times i open my laptop.
That is the network-manager status:

```
> sudo service network-manager status
```

[image]

I know that I have remove something about a Network Group. Thanks a lot of for helpful people. I'm sry for spell mistake, I'm not really good in it...

Comment: Can you not connect in any way

Comment: I can but.... its not well to write all logins the same code.

Comment: Try running package repair ' sudo apt-get -f install'

Comment: Don't work.... nevertheless thank you

Comment: `nobody` is an important system account. It is used when a privileged program wants to start an unprivileged child. Can you restore `nobody`? It would help if you could recall details of how you deleted `nobody`.

Comment: root@rott:~# nano  /etc/passwd ...i have deleted the line about nobody.

Comment: And it's look like this nobody:x:0:x:0:noexist:/root:/bin/...

Answer (score 0):

It's done...I have looked for the nobody code in net. http://openbook.rheinwerk-verlag.de/unix_guru/node110.html It's a german web site....If somebody else have this problem copy the code and past it into the /etc/passwd file. :D